# How to display content of an ArrayController inside a CollectionView

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

I am trying to understand how [Ember.CollectionView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html) works and I am having a basic issue with displaying the content of my [ArrayController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html) in the DOM. Here is [my little jsfiddle experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/nevW2/53/) so you can see for yourself. Here is the coffeescript:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()
window.App.initialize()

App.Item = Em.View.create
  tagName:'li'

  willInsertElement: () ->
  console.log "I **WILL** indert the element", this.$()

  didInsertElement: () ->
    console.log "I **DID** insert the element", this.$()

  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("~~ {{view.content.title}} ~~")

App.items = Em.ArrayController.create()

App.items.set('content',[
    Em.Object.create({title:"AN"}),
    Em.Object.create({title:"Epic"}),
    Em.Object.create({title:"View"})
  ])

App.epicView = Ember.CollectionView.create
  classNames: ['epic-view']
  contentBinding: 'App.items'
  itemViewClass: 'App.Item'

App.epicView.appendTo('body')
```

As you can see in the output of that fiddle, I have not been able to figure out how to access and display the title of objects in the list. When I append the view to body using the call to `App.epicView.appendTo('body')` it seems to iterate over the three objects but does not print anything.

Any ideas what am I missing here?

ps: I am using **Ember 1.0pre**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/nevW2/67/

Declare your views (with extend) instead of instantiate them (with create)